# How i resolve Import re attribute error in Vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import, importerror, attributeerror

So I’m not able to use Import re in Vs code python any suggestions how do i resolve it?**Regular expressions** how i get rid of it

> help

Comment: what do you want exactly ?? .. it's already built in so you don't need to do anything 
please put here in the comment what error you are facing

Comment: AttributeError: partially initialized module 're' has no attribute 'findall' (most likely due to a circular import

Comment: @AhmadOmar This is the error i'm facing

Comment: Please check the post, it may answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949562/module-re-has-no-attribute-findall

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.